# Why using useState hook lets me use a non useState property?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Can someone explain me why every time I call `setTest(scrollY)` I can `console.log(scrollY)` every time I scroll and I don't even need to use `test`. But if I don't call it then it only logs scrollY once?

```
const [test, setTest] = useState(0);

useEffect(function () {
  function handleScroll() {
    setTest(scrollY);
}

  handleScroll();
  window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

  return function () {
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
  };
}, []);

return (
  {console.log(scrollY)}
)
```

Comment: How are you setting /updating`scrollY` out of curiosity?

Comment: @NickParsons I don't JavaScript does for me :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/scrollY

Comment: Ah, I see :), usually it would be best practice to create a state for `scrollY` and then set it that way (rather than set an arbitrary state like `test`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default React will re-render the component for any state change, so your console.log is being called during the re-render.

Comment: So basically I can use any property by updating any state which I don't even have to use?

Comment: By chance yes, your using state as a proxy to cause a re-render at which point any variables (whether state variables or not) will be reevaluated if they're part of the render

Comment: That's cool I thought I can only use the state at the re-render.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the Reactive behaviour of ReactJs,
Whenever you call `setTest`, it will update the state `test`, Triggering a rerender of the component.

Hence `console.log` is printing.